# link dont scroll to top of page issue

Tags: menu, scroll

i need some help, please... I got a affixed menu on my page, and i want to when i click on any item of it, the page scrolls back to the top, i would use an anchor, but i already use it to call the pages on each button...

this is my code

```
<div class="span1 menu">
    <ul class="nav">
    <li id='gostou' class='menufixo' title="gostou do filme?"><a href="#resumo" data-toggle="tab" class="link"></a></li>
    <li id='evolucao' class='menuacao' title="evolução"><a href="#graficos" data-toggle="tab" class="link"></a></li>
    <li id='comentarios' class='menuacao' title="comentários"><a href="#mensagens" data-toggle="tab" class="link"></a></li>
    <li id='info' class='menuacao' title="informações"><a href="#infos" data-toggle="tab" class="link"></a></li>
    <li id='assistir' class='menuacao' title="cinemas"><a href="#tab-assistir" data-toggle="tab" class="link"></a></li>
    <li id='tags' class='menuacao' title="cloud tags"><a href="#cloudtags" data-toggle="tab" class="link"></a></li>
    <div class='ferramentas'></div>
    <script>
    $(".menu ul").on("click", "li", function()
        {
            $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass("menufixo").addClass("menuacao");
            $(this).toggleClass("menufixo").toggleClass("menuacao");
        });
    </script>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I've understood based on your "short" requirements.

http://jsfiddle.net/Madthew/NRMhf/

This code is the code used to go to the top of the page (using jQuery):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

If you add:

```
return false;
```

then your href stop working.

Take a look here regarding how to setup the duration:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Instead of using 'fast' and 'slow' you can enter directly the value in millisecond.

The default duration is 400 milliseconds. 'fast' = 200 and 'slow'= 600.

Lower values means faster execution.

In order to let you see that it's working, I just added a div with a fixed height and a black background. When you click to any of the item you scroll to the top.

Comment: it does get the page back to the top, but it make the href in each link stop working and the new pages don't open...

Comment: Try to omit 'return false;'. I'm not getting which is the issue exactly. Do you have additional code?

Comment: i changed return false to return true and now it works perfectly, thanks very much, but now i wonder, theres any way to make its transition faster? i exchanged the slow for fast, but id still want it to be faster, theres any way? Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome :-) maybe push the arrow up usually people forgot to do it :-). In order to make the transition faster you can enter it in milliseconds. Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The default duration is 400 milliseconds. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively.

Comment: thanks again, i was doing it, but i forgot to delete the '', so it wasn't working... your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: No worries! Sometimes I get frustrated cause I'm new here and even if I answer correctly I don't get the arrow up! I don't understand why. I think I need to have a look to the faqs. Maybe you can't still push up cause you don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: yeah man, i tried to give the arrow up, but i can't yet because i don't have enough reputation ... i'm sorry! :(

Comment: You can't just copy text wholesale from other sources and claim it as your own.  http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/